# Error with NSURLSessionDataTask in iOS 10

Tags: xcode8, ios10, nsjsonserialization, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am having an issue with **NSURLSessionDataTask** , while trying to upload a JSON object , I am getting the following message in console .

```
[] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received 
[error: [89] Operation canceled]
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is related to `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` settings for Schemes.

disable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` mode by following steps and check:

--- Go in Product ---> Scheme ---> Edit Scheme

--- in Run Section on the left, select Argument Tab and in Environment Variable Change value as below:

```
Name: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE 
Value: disable
```

[image: img1]